# load output to variables directly powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, output

I have this script to kill VNC precesses and restart VNC service:

```
$ip = Read-Host 'Enter hostname or IP'

& tasklist /s $ip /FI "IMAGENAME eq winvnc*"

$procid_1 = Read-Host 'pid 1'
$procid_2 = Read-Host 'pid 2'

& taskkill /s $ip /pid $procid_1
& taskkill /s $ip /pid $procid_2

Stop-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer $ip -Name "uvnc_service")
Start-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer $ip -Name "uvnc_service")
```

This command

```
& tasklist /s $ip /FI "IMAGENAME eq winvnc*"
```

gives me this output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
winvnc.exe                    3576                            0      2,968 K
winvnc.exe                    4444                            0      5,556 K
```

And I have to enter PIDs (in this case 3576 and 4444) manually to variables $procid_1 and $procid_2

Is there any way how to pass tasklist output directly to variables?

Thanks in advance for any hints!
Josef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Get-Process` cmdlet instead of `tasklist` - `Get-Process` will output real live .NET objects, so you can grab the `Id` property directly using dot notation:

```
$RemoteComputer = Read-Host 'Enter hostname or IP'

Get-Process -Name winvnc -ComputerName $RemoteComputer |ForEach-Object {
    & taskkill /s $ip /pid $_.Id
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives me this error
`Stop-Process : Feature is not supported for remote machines.
At C:\Users\barcuchj1-a\Downloads\Scripty_testing\VNC\VNC_restart_v0.1.ps1:3 char:46
+ Get-Process -Name winvnc -ComputerName $ip | Stop-Process -Force
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-Process], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand`

Comment: Excelent! Your solution works like a charm!
`SUCCESS: The process with PID 7564 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 7708 has been terminated.`

Thank you so much!